Parquet Partition Strategy for single small file and read Optimization
I have single parquet file ranging from 5 to 100Mb of Data.
While i tried to create partition on Date column multiple files are getting created which reduces the read performance as there are many small files.
Hence i used repartition(1) to create only single file.
Now the query used on this file using Spark sql is date range query like date between x and y.
public DataFilter applyValuationDateRangeFilter() {
    AlcyoneDate startDate = calculationContext.getDateSequence().getStartDate();
    AlcyoneDate endDate = calculationContext.getDateSequence().getEndDate();
    filterQueries.append(" AND ");
    filterQueries.append("ValuationDate BETWEEN '").append(startDate).append("' AND     '").append(endDate).append("'");
    return this;
}

I tried to create partition on ValuationDate column with repartition(1) but didnt get much benefit.
How do i increase my read performance?
I am applying the filter at the time of file loading:
public  Dataset<Row> getDatasetForInputFileWithFiltering(String parquetFilePath, String filterQuery) {
    return getSparkSession().read().format("parquet")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("header", "true")
            .load(parquetFilePath)
            .filter(filterQuery);
}

Also i need to iterate over all the rows to populate some data:
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = rows.toLocalIterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

I am not able to use rows.collectAsList() as it is giving me OOM.
Also not able to use rows.foreach and rows.foreachPartition as my downstream code is not multi threading handled.

Spark usually advises keep files around 128MB with one row group (also 128mb).
In your particular case, partitioning as you said is counter productive, leading in too small files. So the unique parquet file is the way to go, with coalesce(1).
Now for your use case of timestamp filter, you might try to reduce the row group size (spark has a config for that) to something like 5MB and also ordering on your timestamp column. In theory this would lead the reader to skip row groups based on the min/max statistics they have stored, so reading 5MB instead of 100MB.
There is some downsides to having more row groups such as :

more filesystem calls (spark will create one task per row group at least)
less compression efficiency (less data to compress usually makes compression less efficient)

It also means you would end up with more parallelisms than having one onkyvrow group.
BTW if you really need speed, spark is not the best bet, it's designed for fault tolerant ETL, there is more suitable parquet based engines, but this is out of scope.

Just out of curiosity can you please suggest alternative for apache spark for speed for Parquet based files

apache doris or starrocks.

plz let me know it all this was helpful
